# Escape space in bash variable value without quoting

Tags: command-line, bash

In a bash script, we can escape spaces with `\` . Is there any way to do the same from code?

```
$ a=hello\ world
$ echo $a
hello world
$ b=${a:?}  # ? used as dummy; it will not work
$ echo $b
hello\ world
```

*caller.bash*

```
#!/bin/bash
name=$1
if [[ -n $name ]]; then
    where_query="--where name $name"
fi
mycommand $where_query
```

*mycommand*, an external program, we cannot modify. Dummy code added only for illustration purposes.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in "${@}"
do
   echo "$i"
done
```

**Actual**

```
$ caller.bash "foo bar"
--where
name
foo
bar
```

**Expected**

```
$ caller.bash "foo bar"
--where
name
foo bar
```

Comment: The right way to do this kind of thing is with properly quoted elements of an *array* - see for example [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/444949/65304)

Comment: This behaviour is never going to change in bash. I'd advise you to stop fighting and accept that quoting variables is the right thing to do when programming bash. If it's unacceptable to you, then you need to pick a different language.

Comment: Your first example is incorrect; `b=${a:?}` does *not* introduce backslashes into a string where none existed before, nor does `echo`.  `a=foo\ bar` does quote removal when its evaluated, so `a` holds the string `foo bar`.  Copying it with `b=${a:?}` doesn't change that.  You can use `printf "%s\n" "$b" $b`  to show the quoted expansion being a single string with spaces, and the unquoted expansion getting word-split into two args.  (A format string like `_%s_\n` would put other delimiters right on the string so you could detect trailing whitespace.)

Comment: You could also look at the `%q` format to `printf` to escape spaces.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are trying to do is impossible with simple string variables.
You are trying to pass either three parameters or none to the "external program" *mycommand*. You should use bash arrays. Please try the following:

*caller.bash*:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
name=$1
if [[ -n $name ]]; then
    where_query=("--where" "name" "$name")
fi
mycommand "${where_query[@]}"
```

Your scripts have also quoting errors. You should check ***all*** your scripts at https://www.shellcheck.net/ before trying to use them at all.